# R Scrape Atom Feed to a Data Frame

Tags: r, scraper

I'm working on a scraper in R for an Atom feed and having issues grabbing the link for each article.  Here's my code:

```
url <- "http://www.stwnewspress.com/search/?mode=article&q=&nsa=eedition&t=article&l=1000&s=&sd=desc&f=atom&d=&d1=&d2="
pageSource <- getURL(url, encoding = "UTF-8")
parsed <- htmlParse(pageSource)
titles <- xpathSApply(parsed, '//entry/title', xmlValue)
authors <- xpathSApply(parsed, '//entry/author', xmlValue)
links <- xpathSApply(parsed, '//entry/link/@href')
dataFrame <- data.frame(pubDates, titles, authors)
```

My problem is I'm picking up 18 titles, 18 authors, and 20 links.  I think I'm picking up the first two links from the feed page, but I'm not sure how to stop picking them up.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can try using [R does RSS](https://github.com/noahhl/r-does-rss) as well ad @jdharrison's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work from "//entry" rather then the individual nodes. Some entry nodes have multiple links for example:

```
out <- xpathApply(parsed, "//entry", function(x){
  children <- xmlChildren(x)
  title <- xmlValue(children$title)
  author <- xmlValue(children$author)
  links <- children[names(children)%in%"link"]
  links <- sapply(links, function(y){xmlGetAttr(y, "href")})
  data.frame(title, author, links, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})

> out[[1]]
                                            title            author
1 Soap opera star in serious injury crash in Ohio CNHI News Service
2 Soap opera star in serious injury crash in Ohio CNHI News Service
                                                                                                                                                                              links
1                                                                                        http://www.stwnewspress.com/cnhi_network/article_71fb99db-0d47-5ead-9276-cae9c947babc.html
2 http://bloximages.chicago2.vip.townnews.com/stwnewspress.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/d/97/d97a9815-29c8-5b90-be11-41a3a8b12e9f/54354a7b66bd9.image.jpg?resize=300%2C450
> out[[2]]
                                     title                                    author
link Q5: Voter registration deadline nears By Michelle Charles/Stillwater News Press
                                                                                             links
link http://www.stwnewspress.com/news/local_news/article_ba35bd60-4ea4-11e4-8da8-93d495865336.html
```

You can then `rbind` your individual entries together:

```
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, out)
> str(res)
'data.frame':   147 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ title : chr  "Soap opera star in serious injury crash in Ohio" "Soap opera star in serious injury crash in Ohio" "Q5: Voter registration deadline nears" "Oklahoma State assault under investigation" ...
 $ author: chr  "CNHI News Service" "CNHI News Service" "By Michelle Charles/Stillwater News Press" "By Megan Sando/Stillwater News Press" ...
 $ links : chr  "http://www.stwnewspress.com/cnhi_network/article_71fb99db-0d47-5ead-9276-cae9c947babc.html" "http://bloximages.chicago2.vip.townnews.com/stwnewspress.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/d/97/d97a9815-29c8-5b90-be11-41a"| __truncated__ "http://www.stwnewspress.com/news/local_news/article_ba35bd60-4ea4-11e4-8da8-93d495865336.html" "http://www.stwnewspress.com/news/local_news/article_7023a110-4ea4-11e4-82dd-f735d5c5ed44.html" ...
```

To understand how the function works look at the first entry calling it `x`:

```
url <- "http://www.stwnewspress.com/search/?mode=article&q=&nsa=eedition&t=article&l=1000&s=&sd=desc&f=atom&d=&d1=&d2="
pageSource <- getURL(url, encoding = "UTF-8")
parsed <- htmlParse(pageSource)
x <- parsed["//entry"][[1]]
children <- xmlChildren(x)

> names(children)
[1] "title"    "author"   "link"     "id"       "content"  "category"
[7] "updated"

> children$title
<title>BYRON YORK: Jindal a GOP darkhorse in 2016 race</title> 

> xmlValue(children$title)
[1] "BYRON YORK: Jindal a GOP darkhorse in 2016 race"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Unfortunately, I don't exactly understand how it works. Could you elaborate on how that function works?

Comment: I have added an explanation on how it works. Each node given by xpath `//entry` is processed by the function. You can see how the contents of the first node would be processed.